# Calling in Jquery once, rather than as a external source

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am having some issues calling in Jquery from a external source. If i embed this external source the whole page runs the Jquery and it causes some compatability issues with different modules on the page.

What i would like to do is call Jquery once and the close it within the page after it has run a little bit of html but I cannot seem to do this, I have set a JS fiddle to show my issue. The fiddle will not work but i hope it provides a example of my issue

```
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://www.khl.com/other_files/929.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script>
var gstock = ["TYO:5233", "HKG:1893", "HKG:2009", "BIT:IT", "ASX:BLD", "TPE:1101", "NYSE:VMC", "TYO:5232", "NYSE:MLM", "BME:CPL", "HKG:1666", "BKK:SCC"];
$(document).ready(function () {
    for (var i = 0; i < gstock.length; i++) {
        $.getJSON("https://finance.google.com/finance/info?client=ig&q=" + gstock[i] + "&callback=?", function (response) {
            var stockInfo1 = response[0];
            var divContainer = $('*[data-symbol="' + stockInfo1.t + '"]');
            var divCurrency = $('*[data-currency="' + stockInfo1.d + '"]');
            var percentStock = !isNaN(stockInfo1.c) && !isNaN(stockInfo1.l) && stockInfo1.l ? ((parseFloat(stockInfo1.c)/parseFloat(stockInfo1.l)) * 100) : undefined;
            var stockString1 = '<div class="stockWrapper">' + divContainer.data('title') + ':';
            var stockName1 = stockInfo1.t;
            var stockCurency1 = stockInfo1.d;
            var stockPrice2 = "";

            stockPrice2 += '<span class="stockSymbol "> ' + stockInfo1.l + '</span>';     
            var stockChange = "";
            stockString1 += '<span class="stockSymbol "> ' + stockInfo1.t + ' </span>';
            if(!isNaN(percentStock) && percentStock > 0) {
                percentStock = Number((percentStock).toFixed(2));
                stockChange += '<span class="stockChange "> ' + percentStock + ' %</span>';
            } else if(!isNaN(percentStock)) {
                percentStock = Number((percentStock).toFixed(2));
                stockChange += '<span class="stockPrice "> ' + percentStock + ' %</span>';
            } else {
                stockChange += '<span class="stockPrice "></span>';
                stockChange += percentage + '% </span>';               

            }
            stockString1 += stockChange + '</div>';
            $("#title").append("<div>" + divContainer.data('title') + "</div>");
            $("#symbols").append("<div><b>" + stockInfo1.t + "</b></div>");
          $("#currency").append("<div><b>" + $(divContainer).attr( 'data-currency') + "</b></div>");
            $("#livePrice").append("<div>" + stockPrice2 + "</div>");
            $("#liveData").append("<div>" + stockChange + "</div>");
            divContainer.append(stockString1);



        });
    }
});<script></head>

<body>
<div class="container">
<div class="marquee"> 
<div class="19300" data-symbol="5233" data-title="TAIHEIYO" data-currency="JPY" style="display: none;" ></div>
<div class="19400" data-symbol="1893" data-title="CNMC" data-currency="USD" style="display: none;" ></div>
<div class="19500" data-symbol="2009" data-title="BBMG" data-currency="HKD" style="display: none;" ></div>
<div class="19600" data-symbol="IT" data-title="ITALCEMENTI" style="display: none;" ></div>
<div class="19700" data-symbol="BLD" data-title="BORAL" data-currency="AUD" style="display: none;" ></div>
<div class="19800" data-symbol="1101" data-title="TAIWAN CEMENT" data-currency="NTD" style="display: none;" ></div>
<div class="19900" data-symbol="ULTRA" data-title="UTC" data-currency="USD" style="display: none;" ></div>
<div class="20000" data-symbol="5232" data-title="SUMITOMO" data-currency="JPY" style="display: none;" ></div>
<div class="20100" data-symbol="VMC" data-title="VULCAN MATERIALS" data-currency="USD" style="display: none;" ></div>
<div class="20300" data-symbol="MLM" data-title="MARTIN MARIETTA" data-currency="USD" style="display: none;" ></div>
<div class="20500" data-symbol="CPL" data-title="CPV" data-currency="EUR" style="display: none;" ></div>
<div class="20600" data-symbol="1666" data-title="TONG YANG" data-currency="HKD" style="display: none;" ></div>
<div class="20700" data-symbol="SCC" data-title="CIAM" data-currency="THB" style="display: none;" ></div>
<div class="box">
<div id="title" class="floatleft2"></div>
<div id="currency" class="floatleft999"></div>
<div id="livePrice" class="floatleft20"></div>
<div id="liveData" class="floatleft9"></div>
</div></div>
</div>
</body>
```

The above shows my attempt to run the Jquery, and then the html below it. I then want everything to close.

I know this is not the usually way to go about business, but later on in the same page I want to call a very similar bit of jquery which outputs more stocks. What happens is the similar bit of jquery conflicts with the previous piece as the API uses the same names and it will not output on my screen. So I can only ever get one snippet to work

I might well be going about this wrong as I am new to this, but any help would be appreciated.

JS-fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/54p3o3aw/1/

Ultimately I am trying to duplicate this ticker twice on the same page without any conflictions: **https://jsfiddle.net/jhm7po6d/5/**

Comment: If you re-write it as a jQuery extension/plugin, multiple instances will be trivial (and the code simpler to maintain). It will also mean you can cache specific stocks if you need to, to save loading them per instance.

Comment: You can't 'close' jQuery, and even if you could, the conflicts would still be there even if you 're-opened' jQuery later. This is because all the jQuery is doing is letting you select parts of your HTML to modify. Your conflicts are happening because the code is selecting the same parts in both snippets. I suspect that re-writing as a plugin or generic function is probably not feasible for you, so can only suggest that you use these kind of snippets only once on each page to avoid conflicts.

Comment: jQuery extensions are quite easy. Don't be put off doing it a better way *I am sure it is quite feasible for you* :) You will need to start using class selectors and classes (and not IDs however) as IDs cannot be duplicated on a page.

Comment: I would also recommend you create the marquee entries from the data array and not try to sync them up. Each entry would just need additional properties in the array to create the DIVs from data.